# Properly writing multiple json records to a JSON file using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a simple functionality for adding products in JS and I am trying to save this products to a .json file using php.

My json objects in JS look like :

```
{id: 1474791226069, name: "prod", brand: "yhh", price: "2"}
```

And my php for saving them in my .json file is the following:

```
<?php
$data[] = $_GET['data'];

$inp = file_get_contents('products.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($inp);
array_push($tempArray, $data);
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
var_dump($jsonData);
file_put_contents('products.json', $jsonData);
?>
```

Sadly, the result I get in my .json file looks a bit weird :

```
[["{\"id\":1474721566304,\"name\":\"GGG\",\"brand\":\"GG\",\"price\":\"3\"}"],["{\"id\":1474721570904,\"name\":\"GGGH\",\"brand\":\"GGH\",\"price\":\"4\"}"],["{\"id\":1474721574188,\"name\":\"GGGH\",\"brand\":\"GGHH\",\"price\":\"5\"}"]]
```

I've found it imposible to, let's say, look for a product by ID and delete or update it. 
I know a .json file is not supposed to look like this, so **my question** is :  How to make my .json file to look like a normal .json and still to be able to append new .json records from my JS, aka this:

```
[
    {"id":1,"product":"one", "brand":"blah","price":"1"},
    {"id":2,"product":"two", "brand":"blah","price":"2"},
    {"id":3,"product":"three", "brand":"blah","price":"3"}
]
```

So I can be able to add new records, and decode/encode it in a more conventional way?

Please help!

Comment: Do `var_dump($_GET['data']);` and show us what you're getting?

Comment: also var_dump your $inp and $tempArray to see at which point the data is broken

Comment: in $inp i am getting string(237) "[["{\"id\":1474721566304,\"name\":\"GGG\",\"brand\":\"GG\",\"price\":\"3\"}"],["{\"id\":1474721570904,\"name\":\"GGGH\",\"brand\":\"GGH\",\"price\":\"4\"}"],["{\"id\":1474721574188,\"name\":\"GGGH\",\"brand\":\"GGHH\",\"price\":\"5\"}"]]"

Comment: $tempArray is array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(58) "{"id":1474721566304,"name":"GGG","brand":"GG","price":"3"}" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(60) "{"id":1474721570904,"name":"GGGH","brand":"GGH","price":"4"}" } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(61) "{"id":1474721574188,"name":"GGGH","brand":"GGHH","price":"5"}" } }

Comment: $_GET['data'] is shown in the question, it is a json object like this {id: 1474791226069, name: "prod", brand: "yhh", price: "2"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comment,

> $_GET['data'] is shown in the question, it is a json object like this {id: 1474791226069, name: "prod", brand: "yhh", price: "2"}

When decoding a json object, always pass the second parameter as `true` to convert the objects into associative arrays. Also, you have to use an additional array, for example, `$resultData` to achieve the desired result. So **the solution** would be like this:

```
$resultData = $tempArray = array();

$data = json_decode($_GET['data'], true);
if(($inp = file_get_contents('products.json')) != false){
    $tempArray = json_decode($inp, true);
}

array_push($tempArray, $data);
$resultData[] = $tempArray;
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
file_put_contents('products.json', $jsonData);

var_dump($jsonData);
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives a result like this in the products.json : [{"id":1474796685137,"name":"ddd","brand":"ddd","price":"324"},{"id":1474796690417,"name":"ds","brand":"dsd","price":"44"},{"id":1474796699175,"name":"ds34","brand":"dsdg","price":"4434"}], which is exactly the thing i was looking for! :)

Comment: @joysdepraved Glad I could help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should call `var_dump($tempArray);` after `array_push($tempArray, $data);`

Maybe problem is at array structure by itself.

A code like this:

```
$item['id'] = 1474721566304;
$item['name'] = 'GGG';
$tempArray[] = $item;
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
var_dump($jsonData);
```

results in this output:

```
string(35) "[{"id":1474721566304,"name":"GGG"}]"
```

Answer (score -1):

I know I am little bit late, but I figured something out, and this is kinda more convenient and easy to understand. I hope you might get it too. And if in future, people won't understand the accepted code, they will surely understand this.

**CODE:**

```
<?php
   //load data
   $data = file_get_contents($_GET['data']);

   //decode json to associative array
   $json_arr = json_decode($data, true);

   //add data
   $json_arr[] = array(
        "id" => 3, 
        "product" => "three", 
        "brand" => "blah", 
        "price" => "3"
   );

   //encode the json and save to file
   file_input_contents('products.json', json_encode($json_arr));

   print_r(json_encode($json_arr));
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[
   {
     "id":3,
     "product":"three", 
     "brand":"blah",
     "price":"3"
   }
]
```

I have only added single data, but when you add the other data, you will get the desired results only.

Thanks. I hope it might be useful for somebody in the future. Happy Learning!!